# How do you interpret prediction output in GBM() in R for classification problem?

Tags: classification, boosting, adaboost

I created a model using the gbm() function in library(gbm).  Within the gbm() function, I set the distribution as "adaboost".  I have a binary response [0, 1].  I used the predict.gbm function for prediction, but the output is not [0, 1], but real numbers that are both negative and positive.

If within my predict.gbm function, I set type = "response", I believe I get the probability of Y | X = 1.  Is this correct?

If I do not set type = "response" what are those values?  How would I manually convert it to probabilities?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*According to `gbm`'s [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf)*: While indeed `type="response"` then `gbm` converts back to the same scale as the outcome this currently will be returning probabilities for `bernoulli` and expected counts for `poisson` only. For all other distributions `response` and `link` return the same.
That said, `gbm.predict` will indeed transform the response when the assumed cost function is Adaboost.

Here is a small R example about it:

```
rm(list=ls())
data(abalone, package = "AppliedPredictiveModeling") 
library(data.table)  
library(gbm)
setDT(abalone)  
K = 3000
set.seed(3)
gbm_ber <- gbm(as.numeric("M"==Type) ~ Diameter + WholeWeight + ShellWeight + Height, 
               data=abalone[1:K,], distribution="bernoulli")
gbm_ada <- gbm(as.numeric("M"==Type) ~ Diameter + WholeWeight + ShellWeight + Height, 
               data=abalone[1:K,], distribution="adaboost")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(density(predict(gbm_ber, newdata=abalone[-c(1:K),], n.trees=100, type="link")),
     main="Bernoulli - Link")
plot(density(predict(gbm_ber, newdata=abalone[-c(1:K),], n.trees= 100, type="response")),
     main="Bernoulli - Response")
plot(density(predict(gbm_ada, newdata=abalone[-c(1:K),], n.trees=100, type="link")), 
     main="Adaboost - Link")
plot(density(predict(gbm_ada, newdata=abalone[-c(1:K),], n.trees=100, type="response")), 
     main="Adaboost - Response")
```

[image]

As we can see the `response` predictions are indeed between $[0,1]$ for Adaboost too. The manually conversion to probabilities between the `link` predictions and `response` predictions in the case of Bernoulli requires the using the [inverse logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit): $\frac{1}{1+exp(-x)}$ while for the Adaboost is  $\frac{1}{1+exp(-2x)}$. The $2$ comes directly from the inversion of $\frac{1}{2} \ln(\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon})$, see Schapire (2013) "[Explaining Adaboost](http://rob.schapire.net/papers/explaining-adaboost.pdf)" for more details. 
We can see the the manual calculations here:

```
predict(gbm_ada, newdata=abalone[K+c(1:4),], n.trees=100, type="response")
# [1] 0.4851037 0.4913199 0.4791932 0.5135091
predict(gbm_ber, newdata=abalone[K+c(1:4),], n.trees=100, type="response")
# [1] 0.4730339 0.4943825 0.5105203 0.5063024

1/(1+exp(-2*predict(gbm_ada, newdata=abalone[K+c(1:4),], n.trees=100, type="link")))
# [1] 0.4851037 0.4913199 0.4791932 0.5135091
1/(1+exp(-1*predict(gbm_ber, newdata=abalone[K+c(1:4),], n.trees=100, type="link")))
# [1] 0.4730339 0.4943825 0.5105203 0.5063024
```